# Excel vba report

Tags: excel, vb6, extract

I'm building an excel report in vb6. What I'm doing is walking through a recordset and inserting text into a cell. I'm trying to see if there is a way for me to dynamically merge center 2 cells, and put borders around it. This is what my code looks like....

```
Do While Not g_RS.EOF
    xlSheetInsurance.Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS("Label")
    xlSheetInsurance.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlCol).Value = " Count Sales "
    xlSheetInsurance.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlCol + 1).Value = "Count Buys "
     xlCol = xlCol + 2
    g_RS.MoveNext
 Loop
```

So the 'label' gets insert into every other column. Below the label I'm inserting COUNT SALES and COUNT BUYS, so basically I'm trying to take the value of LABEL, merget and center it over two cells so the 2 columns below it look like they belong to the label - and because I'm inserting a lot of label, i want it to look somewhat professional.

EDIT : 
I created macro but I seem to be doing something wrong

```
xlSheetInsurance.Cells(xlRow, xlCol).Value = g_RS("Label")
xlSheetInsurance.Range(xlCol, xlCol + 1).Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
End with
```

SO i include this below the LABEL and it's giving me an error "**METHOD Range of object Worksheet failed**"

Comment: Try recording a macro while merging and centering the cells - it should give you the code you need to incorporate into your existing macro.

Comment: @TimWilliams please see edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Do While Not g_RS.EOF
    With xlSheetInsurance.Cells(xlRow, xlCol)

        .Value = g_RS("Label")
        .Offset(1, 0).Value = " Count Sales "
        .Offset(1, 1).Value = "Count Buys "

        With .Resize(1, 2)
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        End With

    End With

    xlCol = xlCol + 2
    g_RS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: what if I wanted to do the same around the COUNT SALES AND BUYS?

Comment: You mean just add borders?

Comment: well since I have LABEL centered above COUNT SALES AND COUNT BUYS, I would like to have a border on the outside of Count Sales and Count Buys just as I do with LABEL so that they look like they belong together. Also, a vertical border would look much better too.

Answer (score 0):

The `Range()` method accepts either a string argument or other valid `Range` objects. It looks like `xlRow` and `xlCol` are numeric values which cannot be supplied to the `Range()` method.

Try changing to `Cells()` instead, which takes numeric arguments for `row` and `column` respectively.

```
xlSheetInsurance.Cells(xlCol, xlCol + 1).Select
```

---

Furthermore, there is no need to select an object in this manner as you can access its properties and methods directly. With this in mind your code can be re-written as:

```
With xlSheetInsurance.Cells(xlRow, xlCol)
    .Value = g_RS("Label")
    With .Offset(1, 0)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    End With
End with
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not work. I pasted it exactly as you wrote it